# Unity c# smoothly scaling an object that's height is constantly being modified

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale, fft

So far I have a cube thats Y scale reacts to the music being played, but its movement is very sporadic and one second it will be very high and the next very low. How can I get it to only take the highest value and scale to that and then slowly move down towards its initial scale unless another value that is higher than its current scale is called.

```
public class _FFT_Obstacles : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject cube01;
public GameObject cube02;
public GameObject cube03;
public GameObject cube04;
public GameObject cube05;

private float juice = 40f;
private float speed = 5f;

public float[] spec;

public float specMag01;
public float specMag02;
public float specMag03;
public float specMag04;
public float specMag05;

private Vector3 localScale;
private Vector3 newScale;
//The velocity that the cubes will drop  
private Vector3 gravity = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f);

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    localScale = cube01.gameObject.transform.localScale;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    spec = AudioListener.GetSpectrumData(64,0,FFTWindow.Hamming); // this works on audio source
   // spec = AudioListener.GetOutputData(64, 0);  // this gives much  better values.

    specMag01 = spec[2] + spec[4];
    specMag02 = spec[12] + spec[14];
    specMag03 = spec[22] + spec[24];
    specMag04 = spec[32] + spec[34];
    specMag05 = spec[57] + spec[60];

    lerpScale();

    cube01.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f + (specMag01 * juice), 1f);
    //cube02.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f + (specMag01 * juice), 1f);
    //cube03.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f + (specMag01 * juice), 1f);
    //cube04.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f + (specMag01 * juice), 1f);
    //cube05.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, specMag05 * juice, 1f);
}

void lerpScale()
{
   newScale = cube01.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f + (specMag01 * juice), 1f);
  //  cube01.gameObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(originalScale, newScale, Time.deltaTime * speed);
   // newScale.Set(1f, cube01.gameObject.transform.localScale.y, 1f);

    if (newScale.y >= localScale.y)
    {
        localScale.y = newScale.y;
    }
    else
    {
        localScale.y -= gravity.y;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
public class _FFT_Obstacles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FFTWindow window = FFTWindow.Hamming;

    public GameObject cube01;
    public GameObject cube02;
    public GameObject cube03;
    public GameObject cube04;
    public GameObject cube05;

    public float falloff = 3f;
    public float juice = 40f;

    public float[] spec;

    public float specMag01;
    public float specMag02;
    public float specMag03;
    public float specMag04;
    public float specMag05;

    private void Update()
    {
        spec = AudioListener.GetSpectrumData(64, 0, window); // this works on audio source
        // spec = AudioListener.GetOutputData(64, 0);  // this gives much  better values.

        specMag01 = spec[2] + spec[4];
        specMag02 = spec[12] + spec[14];
        specMag03 = spec[22] + spec[24];
        specMag04 = spec[32] + spec[34];
        specMag05 = spec[57] + spec[60];

        UpdateCubeScale(cube01, specMag01);
        UpdateCubeScale(cube02, specMag02);
        UpdateCubeScale(cube03, specMag03);
        UpdateCubeScale(cube04, specMag04);
        UpdateCubeScale(cube05, specMag05);
    }

    private void UpdateCubeScale(GameObject cube, float specMag)
    {
        var currentScale = cube.transform.localScale;
        var newScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f + (specMag * juice), 1f);

        if (newScale.y < currentScale.y)
        {
            newScale.y = currentScale.y - falloff * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (newScale.y < 0f)
        {
            newScale.y = 0f;
        }

        cube.transform.localScale = newScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for thanks for the help, I am never good at working out problems like this logically I just cant think of it in my head...